# Null values when I pass User class to another method

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase, but the problem is when I pass my User class to a method I get null values on all parameters here are the methods:

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: Retrieving data.....");
            FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(mContext);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


public User getUserSettings(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        Log.e(TAG, "getUserSettings: Retrieving Data......");

        User user = new User();

        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if(ds.hasChild(userID)){

                user.setDescription(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getDescription());

                user.setDisplay_name(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getDisplay_name());

                user.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getEmail());

                user.setFollowers(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getFollowers());

                user.setFollowing(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getFollowing());

                user.setPosts(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getPosts());

                user.setProfile_photo(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getProfile_photo());

                user.setUser_id(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getUser_id());

                user.setUsername(ds.child(userID).getValue(User.class).getUsername());
            }
        }
    Log.e(TAG, "getUserSettings: User file"+user.toString());
        return new User();
    }
```

Until here the `Log.e(TAG, "getUserSettings: User file"+user.toString());` gives correct outputs `User fileUser{description='None', display_name='kadiem', email='kazm98@gmail.com', followers='0', following='0', posts='0', profile_photo='None', user_id='L8qHpeb3LpfrzCOHdLVWcEK6XDv2', username='kadiem'}`

Then I have this method

```
private void setupWidgets(User user) {



    Log.d(TAG, "setupWidgets: user data received "+user.toString());

    mDescription.setText(user.getDescription());
    mDisplayname.setText(user.getDisplay_name());
    mUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
    mFollowing.setText(user.getFollowing());
    mFollowers.setText(user.getFollowers());
    mPosts.setText(user.getPosts());
}
```

And here comes the problem when I pass `setupWidgets(firebaseMethods.getUserSettings(dataSnapshot));` to the `databaseReference` The log I get from `setupWidgets(User user)` method conatins null parameters

Comment: From where you did u call setup widget

Comment: Are you sure this: return new User(); shouldn't be: return user; ?

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you so much I don't know how missed that, I must have been tired or something any way thank you so much